# Why does this stop in Python 33

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from math import *

def p():
    for a in range (2, 100):   ##for a in range 2 to 100
        for y in range (2, a): ##for y in range 2, 100
            x = 2*a+1          ##x has the following value
            myprimelist = []   ##creating my empty list   

            if x > y: 
                while (x % y != 0):
                    myprimelist.append(x) ##append to list and continue with the same y  until modulo is zero after which it reaches to else
                    y += 1
                    print (x,'nu se imparte egal la',y)
                    return [y]    ##change the y
                else:
                    y += 1
                    return [y]
            else:
                a += 1
                return[a]
        a += 1
        return[a]

    print (myprimelist);
```

I'm trying to make a function that will tell me all prime numbers from 2 to 100 but for some reason the loop stops and I don'know why. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: got it :D so easy :P can be closed please

Comment: This is not a forum where answered questions are closed afterwards. Here the asker selects one answer which he deems useful and accepts it. Also, upvotes/downvotes helpful/unhelpful answers.

Comment: I've searched for it but couldnt find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` means end of function. Everytime it is encountered the function stops executing.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with python 3, its about return statement. You can try the following code as it checks only from 1 to sqrt(n), as it makes no point trying to check for numbers greater than sqrt(n). Hope this helps.

```
import math
for num in range(1,101):
    if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1)):
       print num
```